# Open source alternatives to PD- Proxy Premium

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, openvpn

I'm looking for a good program that can rival the features provided by [PD- Proxy](http://www.pdproxy.com/premium.htm) which are advertised as:

- a premium user can choose multiple servers located in different locations around the world.
- Connection will not restart every hour
- Unlimited bandwidth

Any free Linux apps? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can try to get any shell of open shell providers... http://shells.red-pill.eu/ - look here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TOR network if anonymity is what you're looking for. Basically, "Tor is a network of virtual tunnels that allows people and groups to improve their privacy and security on the Internet. It also enables software developers to create new communication tools with built-in privacy features" (quoted from the official website). 
TOR provides a client for Ubuntu, you can download it [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en).

Comment: I'm browsing for free using the 100mb free daily data allowance from PD- Proxy. Does this app work the same way PD- Proxy does?

Comment: Technically, the technology used in TOR isn't the same as PD- Proxy, but if you're using PD- Proxy just for browsing anonymousely, TOR is better because it offers unlimited bandwidth since it is a P2P network.

Comment: It seems 12.04 is not supported 8.04 to 11.04 is listed

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you want a VPN is openVPN There pricing is based more on data than by month though https://www.privatetunnel.com/index.php/price.html

Or you could download and set up your own openvpn server This is a guide for 10.04 server https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openvpn.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use **wi-free**, the have an almost similar pricing to pd proxy. Their software connects faster than pd proxy.

Comment: Hi & welcome! Please add link to that program. ;)